# With enlive, how do you get the tag of a link based off of its content?

Tags: clojure, enlive

I've got some html that looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="www.google.com">text</a>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the `a` by using a selector that says "find any link with a content of text"?  I've learned about `text-pred`, but that just returns the text, not the tag with the text.

Answer (score 6):

[I found this answer on the Enlive forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/enlive-clj/text-pred/enlive-clj/thlhc5zBRUw/IUyVzpNwgnUJ). I'll inline it for convenience:

## Question

```
I'm trying to extract the :href attribute from a link which has the
anchor text "Next".  So far I have the following selector worked up.

(html/select tree [:div#nav :span.b :a])

<div id="nav">
<span class="b"><a href="...">Back</a></span>
<span><a href="...">1</a></span>
<span><a href="...">2</a></span>
<span><a href="...">3</a></span>
<span class="b"><a href="...">Next</a></span>
</div>

The problem is that this gives several results (both "Back" and
"Next").  How can I filter this by the text above so I just get the
element I want?  I'd prefer to keep the logic in the css selector
instead of looping through the results if possible...
```

## Answer

```
You have different options:
  [:div#nav :span.b [:a (html/has [(html/re-pred #"Next")])]]
  [:div#nav :span.b [:a (html/has [(html/text-pred #(= % "Next"))])]]
but the simplest is:
  [:div#nav :span.b [:a (html/pred #(= (html/text %) "Next"))]]
and you can make it clearre by rolling your own predicate:
  (defn text= [s] (html/pred #(= s (html/text %))))
  [:div#nav :span.b [:a (text= "Next")]]

#'text works like innerText in browsers so this selector would match <a href='#'><b>Ne<!-- boo -->xt</b></a> too/
```